# Why isn't this design center aligning?

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/C2LAV/

I'm attempting to make the design fill the whole screen unless it exceeds 30% of the total screen width. Then, if it exceeds the 30%, it should center align. Why isn't it doing so?

**updated version, still not working: http://jsfiddle.net/C2LAV/5/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `headerObj`, which isn't defined, you need something like:

```
var headerObj = document.getElementById("header");
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/C2LAV/1/).  For the other piece, the actual centering, you just need to set the `margin`, like this:

```
contentObj.style.margin = "0 auto";
```

[You can test that out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/C2LAV/2/).

Comment: Sorry, I'd cut that out when i posted it, but I had it in the original.  It's still not doing what I want it to do though.

Comment: @DarkLightA - check out the second half of the answer above, is that what you're after?  Just remove the `contentObj.style.textAlign = "center";` if you no longer want the text centered, that's a different style property from the outer alignment.